# ahk click down mouse button while holding down a key on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mapping, mouse, autohotkey

I want to **move the mouse with one hand** while with the other making the button **clicks with the keyboard.**

The difficult part was to instruct AutoHotKey to hold down the mouse button while holding down the key on the keyboard. So you be able to click and drag.

It makes the clicks with the **1**, **2** and **3** keys at the keyboard, in **inverse order** (left click with the 3, as preserving left click with the index finger but of the other hand, trying to mirror the workings inside the brains hemisphere, or something)

This script is activated while **ScrollLock** is **ON** (finally some good use for that beautiful and neglected key, activating all sorts of keyboard shortcuts for AutoHotKey)

Comment: Hey Osman, welcome to Stackoverflow! Great job on solving your question. I would recommend moving the working code to an answer on your own question. This will let myself and other upvote your answer so you can get credit for your findings!

Answer (score 1):

```
#NoTrayIcon

if (GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T")) ; check state for icon
 {
 Menu, Tray, Icon
 return
 }
 else
 {
 Menu, Tray, NoIcon
 return
 }

ScrollLock:: ; From state 0 to state 1 (Activated)
 Send, {ScrollLock}
 Menu, Tray, Icon
 SoundBeep, 261.43, 150 ; low tone
 SoundBeep, 329.63, 150 ; hight tone
return

#If GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ; State 1 (Activated)

 3::
 While GetKeyState("3", "P")
 {
 Click, Left, Down
 KeyWait 3
 Click, Left, Up
 }
 Return

 2::
 While GetKeyState("2", "P")
 {
 Click, Middle, Down
 KeyWait 2
 Click, Middle, Up
 }
 Return

 1::
 While GetKeyState("1", "P")
 {
 Click, Right, Down
 KeyWait 1
 Click, Right, Up
 }
 Return

 ScrollLock:: ; From State 1 to State 0 (Deactivated)
  Send, {ScrollLock}
  Menu, Tray, NoIcon
  SoundBeep, 329.63, 150 ; hight tone
  SoundBeep, 261.43, 150 ; low tone
 return

 ^SPACE:: ; Always on Top Functionality 
  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A
 return

#If
```

Script: **Keyboard-Clicks.ahk**

It gets activated with the **ScrollLock** key.

It **shows the a tray icon when activated.**
It hides the icon when is deactivate it with ScrollLock key again.

Key combination **Ctrl+Space** for **AlwaysOnTop** the currently active window.

It makes a distinctive **sound beep** for activated and de-activated state.

Compiled with an icon from Font Awesome of a hand.

**Font-Awesome-left-hand-paper Icon PNG with Transparency**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYuUj.png